# How to do speech resynthesis to convert female voice into a male one

Tags: voice, speech

I see that there are advanced ML projects already that does text to speech such as SV2TTS : https://github.com/CorentinJ/Real-Time-Voice-Cloning

However what I am looking is rather than text to speech, re-synthesising speech into another voice

So are there any projects, software, library related to this subject that I can utilize?

I have found paid to have services but I need a free one for my experiments

Answer (score -1):

Watson studio is a good software that includes libraries for speech recognition and speech translation. It might be able to help you with what you need to accomplish. I know that R has a built in library for this but it is very limited.

Comment: Well thank you for answer but what I am looking for is voice style conversation. Not translation or recognition.

Comment: You can use Watson Studio for voice style synthesis . I have used it for this purpose. You will need to know either R or Python to create the program. Please upvote my answer if it  helped you. Best of luck with your program